# How can I show data from DB when application load, without delay?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I have SQLite db.  I need to show list from DB when app start, without delay. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Some delay would always be there as accessing data from Sqlite db is itself async task
So it would be better if you have a splash screen before your homescreen/landing page, and meanwhile your splashscreen gets loaded fetch the data